# Нужно ли тире в предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Среди миллионов людей — отыщи своего.
>
> Среди других — выбирают нас.

Нужны ли в этих фразах тире?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно, но возможно (как авторское).